# Continue piping for gulp tasks after returning

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have two gulp tasks I need to run, one for `js`, one for `css`. I need them to run differently for `build-dev` (not minified) and `build-prod` (minified).

To do this, I stripped out the minification and gulp.dest portions of the tasks for `js` and `css` and am instead returning gulp.src to the tasks `build-prod` or `build-dev`. These two tasks `build-prod` or `build-dev` are now responsible for manipulating the `js` and `css` tasks differently.

How can I return the tasks' `gulp.src` to `build-prod` or `build-dev` for continued piping?

**Note**: since it's a stream, it seems I'm returning the stream after the last pipe finishes for that task, then since it's asynchronous, why can't I chain pipes after `gulp.src` returns?

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/**.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(concatCss('main.css'));
        // .pipe(minifycss())
        // .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('js', ...
    return gulp.src(['./js/**/*.js'])
       .pipe(
           ... // Huge function that I don't want to duplicate
});

gulp.task('build-prod', function() {
    gulp.run('css')
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));

    gulp.run('scripts')
        .pipe(minifyjs())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

gulp.task('build-dev', function() {
    gulp.run('css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));

    gulp.run('scripts')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a function you call in multiple places?

```
function cssTask() {
  return gulp.src('css/**.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
    .pipe(concatCss('main.css'));
}

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return cssTask();
});

gulp.task('build-prod', function () {
  cssTask()
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('build-dev', function () {
  cssTask()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use gulp conditionals: `.pipe(gulpif(isProduction, minifycss()))`

[Gulp If](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) is a great way to do it.

```
let isProduction = false;
...
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/**.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(concatCss('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulpif(isProduction, minifycss())) // conditional
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('build-prod', function() {
    isProduction = true;
    gulp.run('css');
});

gulp.task('build-dev', function() {
    isProduction = false;
    gulp.run('css');
});
```